# How to read the binary of an audio file

Tags: matlab, audio, steganography

I wrote program in matlab to hide text and binary image inside an image using LSB embdding steganography. Now I want to hide an audio file inside the image, but I don't know how to covert the wave to binary bit.

Can anyone help me what I must put or change in the program for it to become suitable for hiding audio?

I put this code to convert the wave to bytes but I didn't get anything.

```
 bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes('myAudioFile.wav');
```

Comment: Have you tried `audioread`? https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. The command doesn't look like Matlab to me. You've also said that you can hide binary images, so that must mean you know what to do once you get the byte array of a file. So... are you just struggling with how to read the bytestream of a file in Matlab?

Comment: Matlab code: `f = fopen('myAudioFile.wav', 'r');bytes = fread(f, '*uint8');fclose(f);`

Comment: thank you for help .it was work

Comment: but I get the histogram of cover image similar to stego image when I used color image. I dont know why  .my code is